# Как вывести в один div все элементы h3 из определенной section?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Есть упрощенный код:

```
<div id="sidebar"> ... </div>
<section id="vacancies"> ...
     <div class="vacancy-container" id="id1"> ...
       <h3><a href="#id1">Вакансия 1</a></h3> ...
     </div>
     <div class="vacancy-container" id="id2"> ...
       <h3><a href="#id2">Вакансия 2</a></h3> ...
     </div>
<section>
```

Это страница вакансий. Мне нужно разместить в `sidebar` ссылки на все вакансии, т.е. фактически содержание всех `h3` в section `id="vacancies"`.

Знаю, что JQuery к сайту не подключали, думаю, возможно решения были не нем, честно говоря, я их не отличаю. Плюс может дело осложняется тем, что блок с контентом расположен ниже блока с сайдбаром.

Плюс PHP использовать очень проблематично, т.к. дело происходит в вордпрессе в редакторе страниц, где без доп. плагинов не вставить фрагменты кода PHP. Я могла бы перенести sidebar в шаблон страницы, но section перенести не могу, т.к. вакансии постоянно редактируют люди почти без навыков HTML.

Поэтому прошу подсказать решение, желательно или чистым JS, можно в теге `<script>`, или в шаблоне страницы в вордпресс в PHP.

Comment: Много воды.. Исправьте вопрос, выкиньте истории и эмоции, опишите нормально задачу и что как сейчас сделано ("вакансий" в ВП нет. А вот JQuery как раз есть.).

Comment: Не знала про Jquery, спасибо. Вакансий как типа поста или другой сущности нет, это просто разметка страницы вакансий с классами и id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам надо просто достать всё что внутри `h3` и скопировать в `sidebar`:

```js
const sidebar = document.querySelector('#sidebar');
const vacancies = document.querySelectorAll('#vacancies h3');

vacancies.forEach(vacancy => sidebar.innerHTML += vacancy.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<section id="vacancies">
     <div class="vacancy-container" id="id1">
       <h3><a href="#id1">Вакансия 1</a></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="vacancy-container" id="id2">
       <h3><a href="#id2">Вакансия 2</a></h3>
     </div>
<section>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: @AlexaNazarova не забываем ставить галочку, если ответ решил вашу проблему)

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыла реально) Еще раз спасибо за решение!